Electrical 220V Circuit
I have a 2 pole 60 Amp circuit feeding my barn. Checking the circuit, I am reading 42 amps on one leg & just 10 amps on the other leg. Any suggestions of issues & how much of a problem this could be?

could be fine,  what's using electricity in your barn.

Picture of the panel and description of the loads would help.

If most of the 120v loads that are on, are more on one side that the other, it might be the reason.  Both legs should be ~close to 120v.  The amps is just the amount of power being used on each leg.  A problem only if everything is 240v

Thanks everyone, very helpful. It appears to be fine, I turned in some other things & checked again & it was 43A on one leg & 23A on the other, so it appears to be working as it should
